# Why can I store and retrieve numbers in the Integer Protocol?

Tags: swift

I've seen a few people getting confused between `Integer` (a protocol) and `Int` (a type) in Swift. I think I understand the difference between them, and I get why you can't add `Integer`s together—it doesn't make sense to add two protocols.

However, I'm wondering why this works at all:

```
var x:Integer = 3
println(x) // Prints 3
```

If `Integer` is just a protocol, how come it can store and retrieve an integer value? (And wouldn't it lead to less confusion among Swift beginners if it *didn't* work?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any variable can use a [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Protocols.html) as it's type if all you need is something that conforms to that protocol.

So the int value `3` which you're assigning is being put into a variable where only things (methods, operators, properties, etc) specified in the `Integer` protocol are available.

This is useful for things like delegates where you don't really care what the concrete type of an object is, as long as it supports the functionality you need (as specified in your protocol)

This is covered in some depth in the ["Protocols as Types" section (Protocols chapter) of the swift book](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_352)

Comment: So essentially it's inferring the type but applying the protocols you explicitly name?

Comment: @FernandoMazzon yes the compiler *does* know the type all along (and I believe you can access it using `.dynamicType` but don't quote me on that) but in order to support things like delegates, it allows you to use a protocol as the type and (in the interest of safety) only allows you to use the parts of that variable that are specified in the protocol. This is basically [**duck typing**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) in swift :)

Comment: Ah, yes, of course; I think I'd just been blindsided by the fact that integer is such a simple type and I'm not used to protocols for things that fundamental (or references not looking obviously like references.) That and trying to learn a new language at about nine different levels of thought :) Thanks!

Comment: @MattGibson if you can spare the time, definitely download the WWDC app and watch the Swift talks (Intro, intermediate, advanced, 1 hr each). The "Integrating swift with Objective-C" and "Swift interoperability in depth" (also 1hr each) were also helpful, if a little less so.

Comment: @Jiaaro Thanks; I've watched all except Interoperability In Depth s far—I think I'm just drowning in new information :)

Comment: @jiaaro the compiler no longer knows the type once you assign it to an Integer.  `.dynamicType` is a run-time operation that recovers the concrete type.

Comment: @David I suppose that's true. I was thinking along the lines of, since the program allocates memory and operates on the value, it does know the type behind the scenes, but on the other hand if you pass `x: Integer` somewhere else you'll have to cast it to an int. The compiler won't automagically "know" the type

Answer (score 0):

Since 3 is an `Int`, and since `Int` implements the `Integer` protocol, then var x can very well reference the instance `3`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  1> var x:Integer = 3
x: Int = <read memory from 0x7fd3dc465760 failed (0 of 8 bytes read)>
  2> var y:Int = 3
y: Int = 3
```

It's not the same thing. However, since `Int` implements `Integer`, you might get results that make sense when used in certain cases (like `println`). Don't rely on it though!

Comment: It *does* work, but depending on what is specified in the `Integer` protocol, printing the value may be weird